# Get Values on array from array Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i am making a schedule tasking in laravel, and i need to know the value for other table and, in this case i get the properties and later i save the periods in array from a foreign key in the tables properties, later i need value from "date" in the table periods, but when i get the log i get this.

```
[2017-07-21 18:11:50] local.INFO: [{"id":5,"title":"Hola","date":"2017-07-25"}] 
[2017-07-21 18:11:50] local.INFO: [{"id":4,"title":"dsfsd","date":"2017-07-26"}]
[2017-07-21 18:11:50] local.INFO: [{"id":4,"title":"dsfsd","date":"2017-07-26"}]
[2017-07-21 18:11:50] local.INFO: [{"id":4,"title":"dsfsd","date":"2017-07-26"}]
```

And i cant access to the index with $v->{"id"}, $v->id, $v["id"], i dont know if is for the way i save the information in dates, this is my function, thanks.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {

        $properties = DB::table( 'properties' )->where( 'status', '=', 1 )->whereNotNull( 'id_client' )->whereNotNull( 'id_period' )->get();

        $dates = array();

        foreach ($properties as $k => $v) {
            $dates[$k] = DB::table( 'periods' )->where( 'id', '=', $v->id_period )->whereDate('date', '>', date('Y-m-d'))->get();
        }

        $properties_status = array();

        /* ----- HERE ---------*/
        foreach ($dates as $v) {
            Log::info($v);
        }


    })->everyMinute();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is JSON. It's a kind of data format. You can decode it in PHP by using:

```
$var = json_decode($v, true);
```

And in `$var` you will get a normal array. Which you can simple check with `print_r($var);`.

---

**Manual**

[PHP: json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Thanks, i know it jajajja

Answer (score 1):

You should `json_decode($v)` so you can treat it like a struct. Otherwise it's just a string to you.

Answer (score 0):

`DB::table()->get()` returns a collection, so this will work:

```
Log::info($v->id);
```